# How to check if a particular record already exist in a record using apex class trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, custom-object, duplicate-management, id-comparison

i am having some problem in solving a particular record.
problem - **Repeated Units should not be allowed to be created for same building. Error to be thrown as (Another Unit with same specs already exists)**

Building name a foreign key in unit object.
below is my code can u help me

[image]

[image]

***can any expert help me solve this.***

Comment: Can you add the code in your question.

Comment: I suggest you to add the code as text instead of screenshots. It is also not clear to me if instead you could not simply use Duplicate Rules instead of going for a trigger, what have you tried where have you got stuck?

Answer (score 1):

Pass these parameters in you method accordingly. I gave you the basic idea you can manipulate the code acc. to your requirements..

```
if(Trigger.isAfter ||  Triger.isInsert){
    checkDuplicate(Trigger.new,Trigger.newMap,null);
}
if(Trigger.isAfter ||  Triger.isUpdate){
    checkDuplicate(Trigger.new,Trigger.newMap,Trigger.oldMap);
}

//Trigger.new = newList,
//Trigger.newMap = newMap,
//Trigger.oldMap = oldMap

public static void checkDuplicate(List<Unit__c> newList,Map<Id,Unit__c> newMap, Map<Id,Unit__c> oldMap){
    Map<String,Id> nameToIdMap = new Map<String,Id>();
    for(Unit__c u : newList){
        if((oldMap == null || u.Building_Name__c != oldMap.get(u.Id).Building_Name__c) && u.Building_Name__c != null){
            nameToIdMap.put(u.Building_Name__c,u.Id);
        }
    }
    if(!nameToIdMap.isEmpty()){
        for(Unit__c u : [SELECT Id,Building_Name__c FROM Unit__c WHERE Building_Name__c IN: nameToIdMap.keySet()]){
            if(nameToIdMap.containsKey(u.Building_Name__c)){
                newMap.get(nameToIdMap.get(u.Building_Name__c)).addError('Duplicate Found');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, We need to throw error if Building_Name is same in the existing records right?

Then

1. To throw the *validation* we need to run our logic in ***before events*** (From our trigger its executing on after events that we need to change)
2. We need to Collect all Building_names in one set
3. We need to query Based on above Building_names  set and compare

**Trigger:**

```
List<Unit__c> units = new List<Unit__c>();

if(Trigger.isBefore ){
    if(Trigge.isUpdate){
        for(Unit__c unit : trigger.new){
            if(unit.Building_Name__c != trigger.oldMap.get(unit.Id).Building_Name__c){
                units.add(unit);
            }
        }       
    }else if(trigger.isInsert(){
        units = trigger.new;
    }
    UnitException.sameBuildingException(units);
}
```

**UnitException Class/sameBuildingException:**

```
Set<String> Building_NameSet = new Set<String>();
// Collecting all Building_Name__c
for(Unit__c unit : units){
    Building_NameSet.add(unit.Building_Name__c);
}

// querying existing records with new Building_NameSet

for( Unit__c unit: [Select Building_Name__c 
                    FROM Unit__c
                    Where Building_Name__c In: Building_NameSet]){
    if(Building_NameSet.contains(unit.Building_Name__c)){
        Building_NameSet.remove(unit.Building_Name__c);
    }
}

for(Unit__c unit : units){
    if(!Building_NameSet.contains(unit.Building_Name__c)){
        unit.addError(new Exception('Ur error msg');
    }
    
}
```